# Beautifulsoup : href link is undifined

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrap a website, when I reach any  tag the link is  "job/undifined" , I used post request to fetch data from the page :

post request with postdata in this code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

postData = {
 'search': 'search',
 'facets[camp_type]':'day_camp',
 'open[choices-made-content]': 'true'}

url = 'https://www.trustme.work/en'
html_1 = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=postData)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_1.text, 'lxml')
a = soup1.select('div.MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 ')
b = soup1.select('span[class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h2"]')
print('soup:',b)
```

sample from the output :

```
<span class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h2" style="cursor:pointer">
    <a href="job/undefined" style="color:#413E52;text-decoration:none">
    Network and Security engineer
    </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### EDIT

Part of content is served dynamically so, you have to fetch the jobs hashid via api and then create the link yourself or use the data from JSON response:

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://api.trustme.work/api/job_offers?include=technologies%2Cjob%2Ccompany%2Ccontract_type%2Clevel'
jobs = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()['included']['jobs']

['https://www.trustme.work/job/' + v['hashid'] for k,v in jobs.items()]
```

---

To get the links from each job post change your `css selector` to select your elements more specific, also try to use static identifiers or HTML structure over classes:

```
.select('h2 a')
```

To get a `list` of all links use a list comprehension:

```
['https://www.trustme.work' + a.get('href') for a in soup1.select('h2 a')]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

postData = {
 'search': 'search',
 'facets[camp_type]':'day_camp',
 'open[choices-made-content]': 'true'}

url = 'https://www.trustme.work/en'
html_1 = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=postData)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_1.text, 'lxml')
['https://www.trustme.work' + a.get('href') for a in soup1.select('h2 a')]
```

Comment: Using sepcial css selectior did solve the problem, but found that the dynamic load of the website wasn't the problem, the problem was that the site had an error where there's an empty div had same 'a' tag class name with invalid href, but with CSS selectors I found it and found the target 'a' tags, thanks again